# django variable of one view to another from session

Tags: django, session, csv

I m very confused on this and I dont have any idea how to do this..
I have a view where I have listed all the news from my news table. To display the news I have passed context data in list view. Here is my view

```
class SingleNewsView(ListView):
model = News
form_class = SearchForm
template_name = "single_news.html"

# def post(self, request, **kwargs):
#   print "request"
#   form = SearchForm(request.user)



def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):

    #form = SearchForm(request.user)
    self.pk = pk

    self.pub_from = request.GET.get('pub_date_from',False)
    self.pub_to = request.GET.get('pub_date_to',False)
    self.crawlers = request.GET.get('crawler',False)


    print self.crawlers


    return super(SingleNewsView,self).get(request,pk, **kwargs)



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(SingleNewsView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["form"] = SearchForm
    if self.pub_from and self.pub_to and self.crawlers:
        context["something"] = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk).filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to), crawler=self.crawlers)
    else:
        context["something"] = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk)

    return context
```

and I have written view that I referenced from django doc to download the news in csv format.. I have also included a search form to filter the news. In my first view I have passed context["something"] to display the list of news in the template. 
Now what I want is to download that news in csv. I have written a view for this

```
def CSVView(request):

response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv"'

some_val = request.session["something"]
print some_val
print "this"

writer = csv.writer(response)


writer.writerow(some_val)
return response
```

This is my next view to download the csv. Here what I am trying to do is to download the news that come after filter. In my first view context["something "] gives the list of news. I did all but dont know how to get it. Lastly I m trying to get the value of contxt["something"] from session but I am failed in that too. How can I get the value of one view to another. Or anyone have better idea how can I download the news that is returned by context["something"]. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting data in `context` does not put it in session. You need to set data in session to store it there. Also, storing objects directly in session is not a good idea. You may have to serialize them.

Better way would be create list of `pk`s of objects you want into session.

Something like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(SingleNewsView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["form"] = SearchForm
    if self.pub_from and self.pub_to and self.crawlers:
        qs = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk).filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to), crawler=self.crawlers)
    else:
        qs = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk)
    context["something"] = qs
    #set data in session
    self.request.session['something_pks'] = [ i.pk for i in qs ]
    return context
```

Then in `CSVView` you can get them with `request.session['something_pks'] and do the query for objects.

Comment: Thanx man.. And one more question. What if I want to download the news that is returned by context["something"] without session. How can I do that ?? Is there any easier way ??

Comment: You need to use session to pass data to different views.

Comment: Man after following u in my CSVView I did some_val = request.session["something_pks"] and it gives me just the id of news not the news.. what to do