# Get session value from django form

Tags: python, django

I have 2 forms, one is the main one and the other one opens in a modal window.
I need my second form to get the company session value (AIGN_EMP_ID), however, I don't know how to send this value when I call my form from the Context.

First form.py

```
class MayoresForm(Form):
act_cuenta = ()

act_fechaini = DateField(
    widget=DatePickerInput(
        format=Form_CSS.fields_date_format,
        options=Form_CSS.fields_date_opts,
        attrs={'value': Form_CSS.fields_current_date}
    ),
    label="Fecha desde: ",
    required=True,
)
act_fechafin = DateField(
    widget=DatePickerInput(
        format=Form_CSS.fields_date_format,
        options=Form_CSS.fields_date_opts,
        attrs={'value': Form_CSS.fields_current_date}
    ),
    label="Fecha hasta: ",
    required=True,
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.AIGN_OPCIONES = kwargs.pop("AIGN_OPCIONES")
    self.PERMISOS = []  # para recuperar los permisos de la tabla
    __json_values = json.loads(json.dumps(self.AIGN_OPCIONES))
    self.PERMISOS = recuperarPermisos(__json_values, 'con.transaccioncab')
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Obtiene la variable de sesion desde la vista y la asigna al self
    self.AIGN_EMP_ID = kwargs.pop("AIGN_EMP_ID")
    super(MayoresForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['act_cuenta'] = ChoiceField(label='Cuenta: ', choices=self.get_choices(), required=True)

    for form in self.visible_fields():
        # form.field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = Form_CSS.fields_placeholder + form.field.label.lower()
        form.field.widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = Form_CSS.fields_autocomplete
        form.field.widget.attrs['class'] = Form_CSS.fields_attr_class
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_id = Form_CSS.getFormID(self)
    self.helper.attrs = Form_CSS.form_attrs
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    self.helper.form_error_title = Form_CSS.form_err_title
    self.helper.form_class = Form_CSS.form_class
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-3 text-right form-control-sm'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-6'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            DivHeaderWithButtons(instance_pk=None, remove_create=False, remove_delete=True, remove_print=True,
                                 remove_cancel=False,
                                 permisos=self.PERMISOS,
                                 save_name=' Consultar'),
            Div(
                Div(
                    Div(
                        Div(
                            Div(
                                HTML("<h3 class='card-title'>Buscar por:</h3>"),
                                css_class='card-header'
                            ),
                            Div(
                                Div(
                                    'act_cuenta',
                                    css_class='card-body'
                                ),
                                Div(
                                    'act_fechaini',
                                    'act_fechafin',
                                    css_class='card-body'
                                ),
                                css_class="row"
                            ),
                            css_class='card card-secondary'
                        ),
                        css_class='col-sm',
                    ),
                    css_class='row',
                ),
                css_class='card-body'
            ),
            css_class='card'
        ),
        # Grid para el detalle del mantenmiento
        Div(
            DivGridHeaderWithButtons(grid_opts=get_MayoresDetForm(None)),
            # aqui va el detalle
            css_class='col-sm'
        )
    )

def get_choices(self):
    all_tipoaux = Con_Cuenta.objects.filter(cue_grupo='M', cue_estado=1, emp_id=self.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by(
        'cue_codigov').values()
    DOC = [(d['cue_codigov'], d['cue_codigov'] + ' - ' + d['cue_nombre']) for d in all_tipoaux]
    return DOC
```

Second form.py

```
class MayoresPrintForm(Form):
act_cuenta_ini = ()
act_cuenta_fin = ()

act_fechaini = DateField(
    widget=DatePickerInput(
        format=Form_CSS.fields_date_format,
        options=Form_CSS.fields_date_opts,
        attrs={'value': Form_CSS.fields_current_date}
    ),
    label="Fecha desde: ",
    required=True,
)
act_fechafin = DateField(
    widget=DatePickerInput(
        format=Form_CSS.fields_date_format,
        options=Form_CSS.fields_date_opts,
        attrs={'value': Form_CSS.fields_current_date}
    ),
    label="Fecha hasta: ",
    required=True,
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MayoresPrintForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['act_cuenta_ini'] = ChoiceField(label='Cuenta desde: ', choices=self.get_choices(), required=True)
    self.fields['act_cuenta_fin'] = ChoiceField(label='Cuenta hasta: ', choices=self.get_choices(), required=True)

    for form in self.visible_fields():
        # form.field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = Form_CSS.fields_placeholder + form.field.label.lower()
        form.field.widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = Form_CSS.fields_autocomplete
        form.field.widget.attrs['class'] = Form_CSS.fields_attr_class
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_id = Form_CSS.getFormID(self)
    self.helper.attrs = Form_CSS.form_attrs
    self.helper.form_tag = True  # esta etiqueta te dice si renderiza o no la etiqueta form
    self.helper.form_error_title = Form_CSS.form_err_title
    self.helper.form_class = Form_CSS.form_class
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4 text-right form-control-sm'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-7'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div(
                # <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                Div(
                    HTML("<h5 class='modal-title'><b>Buscar por:</b></h5>"),
                    css_class='modal-header'
                ),
                Div(
                    Div(
                        'act_cuenta_ini',
                        'act_cuenta_fin',
                        css_class='card-body'
                    ),
                    Div(
                        'act_fechaini',
                        'act_fechafin',
                        css_class='card-body'
                    ),
                    css_class="row"
                ),
                css_class='modal-body',
            ),
            Div(
                HTML("<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancelar</button>"),
                Submit('PRINT', 'Descargar', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
                css_class='modal-footer',
            )
        ),

    )

def get_choices(self):
    all_tipoaux = Con_Cuenta.objects.filter(cue_grupo='M', cue_estado=1, emp_id=request.session.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by(
        'cue_codigov').values()
    DOC = [(d['cue_codigov'], d['cue_codigov'] + ' - ' + d['cue_nombre']) for d in all_tipoaux]
    return DOC
```

request.session.AIGN_EMP_ID is the value that I would like to obtain, the point is to get to obtain the value of the session from my second form.

view.py

```
import django
from django.db import connection
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import FormView
from appls.con_man.forms import MayoresForm, get_MayoresDetForm, MayoresPrintForm
from vars import rs


class Con_MayoresCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = MayoresForm
    template_name = 'con_reportes/form_mayores.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('con_man:con_mayores_rep')

    # Asigna al kwargs la variable de session desde el formulario
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(Con_MayoresCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_EMP_ID': self.request.session['AIGN_EMP_ID']})
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_OPCIONES': self.request.session['AIGN_OPCIONES']})
        return kwargs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        extra_errors = []
        request.POST._mutable = True
        ctxt = {}
        print(request.POST)
        if 'PRINT' in request.POST:
            mayores_form = MayoresPrintForm(request.POST)
            if mayores_form.is_valid():
                url = rs.ELEMENTS
                url.ID = rs.REP_CON_MOVIMIENTOCUE_RANGO_ID
                url.PARAMETROS = {'p_per_id': self.request.session['AIGN_PER_ID'],
                                  'p_cue_codigov_d': mayores_form.data['act_cuenta_ini'],
                                  'p_cue_codigov_h': mayores_form.data['act_cuenta_fin'],
                                  'p_fecha_desde': mayores_form.data['act_fechaini'],
                                  'p_fecha_hasta': mayores_form.data['act_fechafin']
                                  }
                r = url.getURL(url)
                return redirect(r)
            else:
                ctxt['mayores_form'] = mayores_form
        if 'CREATE' in request.POST:
            try:
                context = self.get_context_data(per_id=self.request.session['AIGN_PER_ID'],
                                                cue_id=form.data['act_cuenta'],
                                                f_ini=form.data['act_fechaini'],
                                                f_fin=form.data['act_fechafin'],
                                                **kwargs)
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
            except django.db.utils.InternalError as e:
                extra_errors.append(str(e))
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data(**ctxt))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = 'Mayores'
        context['url_list'] = self.success_url
        context['MayoresPrintForm'] = MayoresPrintForm()
        ret = []
        ret.append(get_MayoresDetForm(kwargs).to_JSON())
        context['grids_detalles'] = ret
        return context
```

context['MayoresPrintForm'] = MayoresPrintForm() is where I need to send my session value.

template.html

```
{% extends 'body.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block headScripts %}

    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-grids/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-popups/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-lists/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-calendars/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-splitbuttons/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/util_dev.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% crispy form %}

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="imprimir_id" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% crispy MayoresPrintForm %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



{% endblock %}

{% block bodyFooterScripts %}
    <!-- Datepicker libs
    -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
          type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/bootstrap_datepicker_plus/css/datepicker-widget.css" type="text/css" media="all"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap_datepicker_plus/js/datepicker-widget.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("small[id^=hint_]").each(function (index, small_tag) {
                $("label[for='" + small_tag.id.substring(5, small_tag.id.length) + "']").attr('title', small_tag.innerText);
                small_tag.remove();
            });
        });
    </script>

    {# Convierte el grid de texto a un json para maniuplarlo #}
    {{ grids_detalles|json_script:"gr_dets" }}
    {#  importanto libreria js  #}


    <script>
        const gr_dets = get_json_from_script();
        const elem_unimeds = gr_dets[0];

        console.log("elemento de la grid");
        console.log(elem_unimeds);

        //Inicializa el grid (Detalle)
        ej.grids.Grid.Inject(ej.grids.Edit, ej.grids.ExcelExport);
        const grid = new ej.grids.Grid(elem_unimeds.gridOptions);

        //agrega el exportExcel
        grid.toolbarClick = function (args) {
            if (args['item'].id === 'MayorDetalle_id_excelexport') {
                grid.excelExport();
            }
        }

        grid.appendTo("#" + elem_unimeds.grid_id);
        //Se agrega un boton descargar pero sin efecto submit ya que este solo abrirá la ventana modal
        document.getElementById('save_id').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",
            "  <a  id=\"download_id\" class=\"btn btn-dark btn-sm\"><i class=\"fas fa-file-pdf-o\"> </i> Descargar</a>");

        document.getElementById("download_id").onclick = function () {
            $('#imprimir_id').modal('show');
        };


    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

I would really appreciate if you help me with any suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734025/django-pass-session-variables-from-one-view-to-another-request-is-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `get_context` I could send a variable data with the value session `MayoresPrintForm(data=self.request.session)`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['page_title'] = 'Mayores'
    context['url_list'] = self.success_url
    context['MayoresPrintForm'] = MayoresPrintForm(data=self.request.session)
    ret = []
    ret.append(get_MayoresDetForm(kwargs).to_JSON())
    context['grids_detalles'] = ret
    return context
```

But I had to change the Post method to retrieve the form values ​​from there like this: `request.POST['act_cuenta_ini']`

This is the final code:

```
import django
from django.db import connection
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import FormView
from appls.con_man.forms import MayoresForm, get_MayoresDetForm, MayoresPrintForm
from vars import rs


class Con_MayoresCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = MayoresForm
    second_form_class = MayoresPrintForm
    template_name = 'con_reportes/form_mayores.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('con_man:con_mayores_rep')

    # Asigna al kwargs la variable de session desde el formulario
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(Con_MayoresCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_EMP_ID': self.request.session['AIGN_EMP_ID']})
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_OPCIONES': self.request.session['AIGN_OPCIONES']})
        return kwargs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        extra_errors = []
        request.POST._mutable = True
        if 'PRINT' in request.POST:
            url = rs.ELEMENTS
            url.ID = rs.REP_CON_MOVIMIENTOCUE_RANGO_ID
            url.PARAMETROS = {'p_per_id': self.request.session['AIGN_PER_ID'],
                              'p_cue_codigov_d': request.POST['act_cuenta_ini'],
                              'p_cue_codigov_h': request.POST['act_cuenta_fin'],
                              'p_fecha_desde': request.POST['act_fechaini'],
                              'p_fecha_hasta': request.POST['act_fechafin']
                              }
            r = url.getURL(url)
            return redirect(r)

        if 'CREATE' in request.POST:
            try:
                context = self.get_context_data(per_id=self.request.session['AIGN_PER_ID'],
                                                cue_id=form.data['act_cuenta'],
                                                f_ini=form.data['act_fechaini'],
                                                f_fin=form.data['act_fechafin'],
                                                **kwargs)
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
            except django.db.utils.InternalError as e:
                extra_errors.append(str(e))
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data(context))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = 'Mayores'
        context['url_list'] = self.success_url
        context['MayoresPrintForm'] = MayoresPrintForm(data=self.request.session)
        ret = []
        ret.append(get_MayoresDetForm(kwargs).to_JSON())
        context['grids_detalles'] = ret
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, our Syncfusion controls will not have support for your requirements.

Regards,

Gokul

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).